# Erro ao imprimir echo php em div

Tags: php, html, div, echo

Sou um programador amador e estou com um problema ao imprimir uma eco php dentro de uma div.

Eu tenho um arquivo que, quando acessado (uma única vez) irá iniciar a instalação do banco de dados:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); 
try 
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","");

    $mysqli->query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS respostas;");

    $ok = "Banco de dados criado com sucesso...";
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    $error = "Desculpe alguma coisa não deu certo. Detalhes: " . $e->message;
}
```

E exibir o resultado na `<div id="progress">`

```
$pageBody = <<< EOPAGE
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title>Home | Configuração </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="txt/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>  
    <div class="body">
        <div class="text">
            <p><h1>Bem Vindo</h1></p>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <p class="texts"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>Iniciaremos agora as configurações finais. Aguarde enquanto todos os arquivos são configurados.</p>
            <div id="progress">
            <p>Aguardando</p>
            <p>$ok</p>
            <p>$error</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
EOPAGE;

echo $pageBody;
```

No entanto, quando chamo o `$ok` a mensagem é exibida normalmente, mas quando eu chamo o `$erro` não exibe mensagem de erro, mesmo simulado um erro de conexão com o servidor, e o código dá erro.

Comment: Coloca assim e testa <?php echo $ok; ?> e <?php echo $error; ?> diga algu

Comment: @CésarSousa, infelizmente não exibe a mensagem. E quando coloco ambas, `<?php echo $ok;?>` e `<?php echo $error`>, retorna uma mensagem de erro.

Comment: o correto não seria 
$e->getMessage ?

Comment: @IsvaldoFernandes, tentei utilizando o getMessage, no entanto, não funcionou. Mesmo deixando somente o <p>$error</p> e simulando uma falha conexão, não retorna a mensagem, mas sim o erro de código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A estrutura de try/catch que você utilizou deixa uma das variáveis `$ok` e `$error` não definidas (gera o erro "**Notice: Undefined variable**").

Sugiro utilizar apenas uma variavel `$message` para ambos os casos, e se sua lógica necessitar, uma variável true/false indicando se houve erro:

```
$message = "mensagem ok";
$error = false;
try {
    // consultas
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = true;
    $message = "mensagem erro: " . $e->message;
}
```

Nos comentários foi informado para utilizar `<?php echo $variavel; ?>`, mas o código na pergunta usa a [sintaxe heredoc](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) e as variáveis são interpretadas. Para evitar problemas é bom cercar as variáveis dentro de strings com chaves. Exemplo: `$variavel = "Texto com {$outraVariavel}";`

Outro detalhe que percebi no seu código, e que pode estar causando algum erro é em `$pageBody = <<< EOPAGE`, deveria ser `$pageBody = <<<EOPAGE`, sem o espaço antes de EOPAGE

Comment: Seguindo as orientações apresentadas por @Sanção, e algumas pequenas modificações no código, resolvi o problema.